# Как загрузить jpg в rest api?

Tags: nginx, golang, http, rest

Я делаю rest api на go, и у меня встал вопрос, как загрузить фото профиля. Предположим, проксирующий nginx и бэк на go стоят на разных машинах, мне нужно чтоб фото хранилось на машине с nginx и выдавалось им же, но при этом мне нужно сохранить в бд url фотографии. Какие варианты решения есть в данном случае?

Comment: Добавляете [модуль-обработчик](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/) для NGINX, который принимает файлы для сохранения, и проксирует вызов на ваш Go сервер после.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае вы можете сделать следующее:

1. Настроить проксирование запросов на загрузку изображений через nginx. Например, вы можете настроить nginx так, чтобы он перенаправлял запросы на загрузку изображений на отдельный эндпоинт вашего приложения на Go.
2. Создать эндпоинт для загрузки изображений в вашем приложении на Go. Этот эндпоинт должен принимать запрос с изображением в теле, сохранять изображение на диске на машине с nginx и возвращать URL изображения в ответе.
3. Сохранить URL изображения в базе данных. Вы можете сделать это, отправив запрос на вашу базу данных с помощью Go, чтобы сохранить URL изображения в соответствующей таблице.

Вот пример конфигурации nginx, которая перенаправляет запросы на загрузку изображений на эндпоинт /upload-profile-image вашего приложения на Go:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your-nginx-server.com;

    location /upload-profile-image {
        proxy_pass http://your-go-app-server:8000/upload-profile-image;
    }
}
```

В этом примере я предполагаю, что ваше приложение на Go запущено на порту 8000 на сервере с адресом your-go-app-server. Вы также можете настроить nginx на проксирование запросов на загрузку изображений на другой эндпоинт вашего приложения на Go, заменив /upload-profile-image на нужный вам эндпоинт.

Обратите внимание, что в этом примере я указал listen 80, что означает, что nginx будет слушать HTTP-запросы на порту 80. Если вы хотите, чтобы nginx слушал HTTPS-запросы, то вам нужно будет настроить SSL/TLS сертификаты и изменить listen на listen 443 ssl.

Пример прилажухи:

```
func saveProfileImage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Принимаем изображение
    file, _, err := r.FormFile("image")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Сохраняем изображение на диске
    fileName := fmt.Sprintf("%d.jpg", time.Now().Unix())
    filePath := filepath.Join("/path/to/image/storage", fileName)
    targetFile, err := os.OpenFile(filePath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer targetFile.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(targetFile, file)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Сохраняем URL изображения в базе данных
    imageURL := fmt.Sprintf("https://your-nginx-server.com/images/%s", fileName)
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()

    _, err = db.Exec("UPDATE profiles SET image_url = ? WHERE user_id = ?", imageURL, r.FormValue("user_id"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Write([]byte(imageURL))
}
```

Этот код сохраняет загруженное изображение на диске, а затем сохраняет URL